# New to dev, want to make an extension that labels particular Amazon products, how to do this?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make an extension for Chrome that, when active, will label Amazon products that come from a particular company. For example, if the extension reads that in the product page the company was let's say Adidas, I want to the extension to change the text of that product to red. Are there any other extensions that do something similar that I could play around with?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) to setup a basic chrome extension.
In your manifest, you set your content script to match to Amazon product pages.
In your content script you search the body of the page for instances of "Adidas" then you make them red.